# jboss-as-maven-plugin freezes on authentication

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I have jboss 7.1.1 in standalone mode running on machine A (linux).
I want to deploy remotely to it using client machine B @ mac os X 10.8.5 / JDK 1.7.0_45-b18.

If I connect from B to A using `jboss-cli`, everything works fine, I am able to login.

If I try to deploy from maven with this :

```
<groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.5.Final</version>
<configuration>
    <hostname>${deploy.jboss.host}</hostname>
    <port>${deploy.jboss.port}</port>
    <username>${deploy.jboss.user}</username>
    <password>${deploy.jboss.password}</password>
</configuration>

<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

plugin freezes indefinitely on 
`Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm`
No more details are available with `mvn -X`

If I remove the password or username from pom, it fails correctly with :
`The connection failed: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed`
so it seems that the plugin somehow manages to connect to machine A.

After digging on google, I ended up adding `-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider` to mvn runner options because NIOs on jdk7@macosx is said to be buggy but it didn't help.

I opened a bug at jboss ([https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBASMP-58](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBASMP-58?filter=-2)) but if someone thinks of something to try, you are very welcome ;)

---

EDIT :
I made a jstack of maven when it is freezed, revelant stack seems to be :

```
"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007f968d000000 nid=0x1903 in Object.wait() [0x00000001106ba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007ad9a0058> (a org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ActiveOperationSupport$ActiveOperationImpl)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.await(AsyncFutureTask.java:192)
    - locked <0x00000007ad9a0058> (a org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ActiveOperationSupport$ActiveOperationImpl)
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:266)
    - locked <0x00000007ad9a0058> (a org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ActiveOperationSupport$ActiveOperationImpl)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractDelegatingAsyncFuture.get(AbstractDelegatingAsyncFuture.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.isDomainServer(AbstractServerConnection.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.getClient(AbstractServerConnection.java:156)
    - locked <0x00000007ad67ca28> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.isDomainServer(AbstractServerConnection.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007ad67ca28> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.validate(AbstractDeployment.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:136)
    - locked <0x00000007ad67ca28> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Comment: Can you try 7.4.Final of the plugin just to see if it works? This could be a possible remoting issue.

Comment: I tried 7.4.Final and 7.1.1.Final and I am still experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have port 9999 open on the Linux box?

Comment: Yes, as I said, connecting from B to A with jboss-cli works fine. And I guess jboss-as-maven would fail with some explicit error if it was not the case, the problem here is that it's stuck without giving any feedback.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I happen to have a mac next to me so when I can a chance I'll test it.

Comment: Edited post with a jstack. Hope this will help you solve this issue ! Thanks for your time, James.

Comment: Finally got a chance to test this out. Worked for me on OS X 10.9, maven 3.1.1 and JDK 1.7.0_21-b12.

Comment: I upgraded to OS X 10.9 / maven 3.1.1 but still got the same problem. Have you any clue of what could be happening with the above stacktrace ?

Comment: Not exactly sure. I've seen similar results before, but changing versions of jboss-remoting3 seemed to fix it. Try using the 7.1.1.Final plugin just to see if that works.

Comment: nop, it doesn'work with any version in the range 7.1.1-7.5. Starting to feel a little desperate. Is there any way to enable aggressive logging in the plugin so I can surround the problem ?

Comment: Okay, something seems odd then. I'll move the discussion over to the JIRA.

Comment: Okay, i edited the JIRA and have added stacktraces